# How to make a navbar shrinks its size in the same proportion as the image within it when the window is made smaller

Tags: html, css

I have a navbar containing an image and a menu.

It looks fine when it is o a maximized but when I try to make the window smaller, the image and the menu are getting smaller but not the navbar which keeps the same height.

I tried many options like using percentage, vh, vw and others but didn't solve my problem.

This is my code:

```css
.main-bar {
  background-color: #212121;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  color: #8a8a8d;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.imgs {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  /* width: fit-content; */
  width: 700px;
  height: 110px;
}

.imgs img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.menu {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 45px;
}

#login {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 2vw;
  margin-top: -10px;
}

.menu_item {
  padding: 10px;
}

.menu_item:hover,
.login:hover {
  color: #E3E3E3;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-bar">
  <div class="imgs">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/SX4tC2y.png" alt="image">
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <span class="menu_item">Houses</span>
    <span class="menu_item">Apartments</span>
    <span class="menu_item">Cars</span>
    <span class="menu_item">Rents</span>
    <span class="menu_item">Others</span>
    <span class="menu_item" id="login">Login</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the fixed height you added to the image container. Remove it and add some padding for spacing:

```css
.main-bar {
  background-color: #212121;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  color: #8a8a8d;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.imgs {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  width: 700px;
  padding-bottom:10px;
}

.imgs img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.menu {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 45px;
}

#login {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 2vw;
  margin-top: -10px;
}

.menu_item {
  padding: 10px;
}

.menu_item:hover,
.login:hover {
  color: #E3E3E3;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-bar">
  <div class="imgs">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/SX4tC2y.png" alt="image">
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <span class="menu_item">Houses</span>
    <span class="menu_item">Apartments</span>
    <span class="menu_item">Cars</span>
    <span class="menu_item">Rents</span>
    <span class="menu_item">Others</span>
    <span class="menu_item" id="login">Login</span>
  </div>
</div>
```